# How to pass datatable as input parameter from C# to stored procedure in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I am passing a `DataTable` as input parameter from C# to stored procedure. For that I created user defined table type called `EmpType`.

The `DataTable` contains columns id, Name, Lname, Mobileno, EmpId.

Employee table contains columns [Name], [Lname], [mobno], [Did]. I want to insert record from datatable to Employee table which are not already present.

Here my SQL code:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[EmpType] AS TABLE
(
    [Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Lname] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [MobileNo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EmpId] [int] NULL
)

Create Procedure Proc_InsertEmpDetails
    @tblEmp EmpType READONLY,
    @DId int
as
begin
    INSERT INTO Employee ([Name], [Lname], [mobno], [Did])
        SELECT 
            [Name], [Lname], [mobno] @DId
        FROM   
            @tblEmp A
        INNER JOIN
            (SELECT MIN(Id) AS minID, mobno 
             FROM @tblEmp 
             GROUP BY mobno) MinIDTbl ON MinIDTbl.minID =  A.ExcelId
        WHERE  
            NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                        FROM Employee B
                        WHERE B.[mobno] = A.[mobno]
                          AND B.[Did] =  @DId) 
end
```

It is working properly. I am using SQL Server 2012. But my development server is SQL Server 2000. SQL Server 2000 does not support user-defined table type.

Is there any alternative way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you upgrade your development server?

Comment: That is not in my hand...

Comment: Prior to table-type parameters, the only way I knew to do this was to pass the records one at a time to a stored procedure that could insert a single record.

Comment: See there are more than 2000 record.Every time open connection,execute and close it.It is time consuming....

Comment: Using XML, see this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163782.aspx